# How to get the custom value from response headers(sending from node.js service) Object in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, header

My problem is related to custom response header.I get the header custom value(token) in Browser Network section Like this :

**Response Headers**:

```
access-control-allow-headers:undefined
access-control-allow-origin:http://localhost:9001
Connection:keep-alive
content-length:255
content-type:application/json
Date:Mon, 16 Mar 2015 09:20:57 GMT
token:BVlcfiQmZmRDmw/OgWqy9h2E2PERyVoXmcscink376NXpcoLkd9nq1qZ1bauUM2jkD2nHG0jGCBO486Z+7xiXPxrk2iP6nJ1y+EKk/NJ61qzGAJ6Py1yVZy5
Vary:X-HTTP-Method-Override
X-Powered-By:Express
```

**But when we want to console whole response object like this**

```
ekgAdminService.userLogin(logInData).success(function (success, status, headers,config) {
                var userInfo = success.data;
                console.log(headers());
}).error(function(){

});
```

**it console these values as**

```
loginController.js:24 Object {content-type: "application/json"}
```

So, I am not getting the token value in headers.

Please provide me the solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `then` instead of `success`, i.e. :

```
yourService.userLogin(logInData).then(function (httpResponse) {
    // handler on success
}, function (httpResponse) {
    // handler on error
});
```

The object httpResponse contains [(link to doc)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) :

- `data` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- `status` – HTTP status code of the response.
- `headers` – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
- `config` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- `statusText` – HTTP status text of the response.

Then read the `config.headers` object

Comment: The error handler would be the second argument. I completed the code to show that.

Comment: Hi michael,

if i use .then  instead of .success then i call our service as 

myService.userLogin(logInData).then(function (httpResponse) {
    console.log(httpResponse.headers());
}
It shows the same result.

Comment: Did you looked at the `config.headers` object?

Comment: I need token value from the headers ,

i am accessing token value like 

`console.log(headers())`
 it returns 
`Content-Type:'application/json'`
As u suggest me , i tried that but unfortunately i got the same result.

I can access content type as
` headers('content-type') `
but i write the same as `headers('token')` it did not respond me the token value which i found in Browser Network response header

Comment: Michael , in success
there are four parameter like `(data,status,headers,config)` so 

you know body contains data and i added a property `token:'custom value'` As you seeing in my question `Response Header` contains token value ,so i need it access from my control

Comment: Does `config.headers.token` give the value?

Comment: No ,`config.headers.token` gives `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at [Angular Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) and make use of response method:

```
'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },
```